# How to output calculated info in POV-Ray animation?

Tags: povray

I'm creating a POV-Ray 3.6.2 (Windows) animation using an *ini* file as usual. In the *pov* file, I calculate several values such as camera position based on the *clock* value. How can I output these values in some way that is easily retrievable for (non-realtime) use in an external program?

In descending priority, these are the methods I thought of:

1. Save it in the filename (instead of the usual filename00.bmp, filename01.bmp etc)
2. Save it in an external text file (either one per frame, or one for the whole animation)
3. Save it in the file metadata (though I don't know whether BMP has metadata fields similar to EXIF tags)

At the moment, I'm using a text object to write it into the image, which can later be manually copied and cropped off.

I know I can rewrite the algorithm that generates these numbers in another language, but rather avoid this because I'll need to maintain 2 copies of the algorithm in case it changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `#debug "Some text"` directive together with the `Debug_File=filename.out` command line parameter to store your output in a file. Note that `#debug` can only accept textual arguments, so consider using the `str()` and `concat()` functions for any numeric data, e.g.:

```
#debug "Output follows"
#debug str(123.456789, 0, 3) // do not pad and round to 3 decimal places: 123.456
#debug concat("Six by six is ", str(6 * 6, 5, 0)) // pad with up to 5 zeroes, omitting decimal places: Six by six is 00036
```

Comment: Thanks, Vadim. For the record, adding Debug_File=on to my ini file and #debug "...\n" to my pov file outputs a DEBUG.OUT text file. The \n ensures that each debug message is on a separate line.